# Load images based on screen size in Boot Strap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Boot Strap 3 for my new responsive layout. For my home page I have background image. Please advise how to use different background images depending on screen resolution. I cannot use responsive class. Please use below URL to review the layout.

http://idea66.com/mobile/screenshot.png

If I create this structure for different screen type, how can we call them using Boot Strap 3.0

Thank you
Monica

Comment: You need to try different things, post your css and html in a JSBin or Fiddle. There's lots of documentation to find: http://voormedia.com/blog/2012/11/responsive-background-images-with-fixed-or-fluid-aspect-ratios

Answer (score 9):

You can have [CSS with media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). Example:

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {

    body {
        background: white url(medium.jpg);
    }

}

@media (max-width: 767px) {

    body {
        background: white url(small.jpg);
    }

}
```

Comment: @ShawnTaylor: A good question... can you access breakpoint variables in pure CSS?

Comment: No, but I actually meant to say the breakpoints themselves: i.e. 768px, 992px, 1200px, and as min-width, not max-width., as per http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid.

Comment: @Swan Taylor you should also mention that the default is set for smallest size (less than 768px). Otherwise your link helped me a lot =)